# Aligning specific text with different widths?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

See snippet, how can I align the text so the `<em>` 's are all on the same line?
Like this

[image]

```css
em {
margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p>Design: <em>lorem ipsum</em></p>
<p>Designsssss: <em>loremloremloremloremipsum</em></p>
<p>Designszzzzzzzzz: <em>ipsum lorem</em></p>
<p>Design and develomment: <em>ipsum</em></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
p {
  display: flex;
}
em {
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p>Design: <em>lorem ipsum</em></p>
<p>Designsssss: <em>loremloremloremloremipsum</em></p>
<p>Designszzzzzzzzz: <em>ipsum lorem</em></p>
<p>Design and develomment: <em>ipsum</em></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Tables can do that:

```css
p {
  display: table-row;
}

em {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p>Design: <em>lorem ipsum</em></p>
<p>Designsssss: <em>loremloremloremloremipsum</em></p>
<p>Designszzzzzzzzz: <em>ipsum lorem</em></p>
<p>Design and develomment: <em>ipsum</em></p>
```